# why the Nvidia profiler does not show unified memory information

Tags: memory, cuda, profiling, nvidia

I have a TitanXP installed in a Windows 10 64bit with CUDA 9.2 and Nvidia driver (398.82-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql), and I have a simple program which uses unified memory like below.

```
// CUDA kernel to add elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
int N = 1 << 20;
float *x, *y;

// Allocate Unified Memory -- accessible from CPU or GPU
cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float));

// initialize x and y arrays on the host
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
}

// Launch kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
int blockSize = 256;
int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
add <<< numBlocks, blockSize >>>(N, x, y);

// Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
float maxError = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));
std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

// Free memory
cudaFree(x);
cudaFree(y);

return 0;
}
```

I compile this code using Visual Studio 2017 community, and run it in the command prompt window with no error.

When I profile it in Nvidia Profiler, it gives me a "Warning" message as below.

```
"==852== Warning: Unified Memory Profiling is not supported on the
current configuration because a pair of devices without peer-to-peer
support is detected on this multi-GPU setup. When peer mappings are
not available, system falls back to using zero-copy memory. It can
cause kernels, which access unified memory, to run slower. More
details can be found at:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-
managed-memory"
```

I am pretty sure I only have one GPU installed in the computer, why I can not get the unified memory profiling information?

By the way, I did the exactly same experiment in my another machine which has the same software environment and same GPU, and the profiler does show the unified memory information. Is there any wrong with that specific computer? Is there any hardware related configuration/setting I need to do in order to enable the unified memory feature?

Answer (score 2):

I had faced this problem in the past, but after updating my driver to the last version (Released in 19/9/2018 if I am not mistaken) the problem resolved.

Hope it will resolve your problem as well. 
Let me know if it did.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the beginning, I install the latest version, and it has this problem, and then I tried an old version as I post here the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

I install the new cuda sdk 10, and it works fine now.